# Loading Animation for large HTML Tables in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a page with a really large table, and I would like to display a loading animation until the table is loaded. At the moment I'm using the following solution. Directly after `<body>` i have a div:

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

And at the end of the page before `</body>` I'm using the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut();
});
```

The problem is, in firefox the page seems to be loaded completely before it is shown. So if I'm on a webpage and I click on a link to my table, firefox is just processing for some seconds and then the whole page with the table is shown. The "loading `<div>`" is just flashing very short - because then the page is loaded really fast. How can I fix that and show my loading div, while Firefox is processing the page?

Comment: try to use `$(window).load(...)` instead and see if it works better for your purpose. Anyway I'd recommend to split your table in several pages, or use ajax to load more cells while scrolling

Comment: I'm using the datatables script for my table, so it already is splitted in pages.

Comment: I added a short movie to show what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the page's head tag

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $("#loading").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: This Definitely works, I'm currently using the script the same way you want. But mine is for loading high quality images.

Comment: No, same behaviour as shown in the movie. Because the whole page is loaded after the 5 seconds timeout, the loading div is displayed after this timeout and then faded out.

Comment: Must have been something with my local testing environment. I published the whole script to the server and there it's working as expected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut();
    $('.tables').css('display', 'none').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

It will give you an illusion of subtle loading.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `div` `#loading` with your loading info / `.gif` that will cover all your page:

```
<div id="loading">
     <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" />
     Loading...
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).load(function(){

   // PAGE IS FULLY LOADED  
   // FADE OUT YOUR LOADING DIV
   $('#loading').fadeOut();

});
```

Instead of `$(document).ready()` use `$(window).load`

Comment: My problem is, that the overlay div is shown after a short timeout of loading, and than it is directly fading out. So Firefox is processing the page, shows the loading overlay and fades it out. I would like to show the overlay while the page is processed, but that doesn't work.

Comment: okay, I must've mis that part. Are you getting the info from an ajax call? What are you using to populate the table? See if you can listen for events. Once the event is done, hide the loader. As I said, I'm not sure what your entire setup is.

Comment: Must have been something with my local testing environment. I published the whole script to the server and there it's working as expected. Thanks for your help.